# Fetching data 3 levels deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My aim is whether is it possible to fetch my required data the fastest way / with the least amount of queries to the database.

---

My Rails models are as follow:

```
AA has_many BB 
BB has_many CC
CC has_many DD
```

I would like to get all `DD` that has `AA.name = "xxx"`

---

I am stuck on the above on not knowing how to use joins to make sure I can get the `DD`s. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use joins passing the reference of each model:

```
DD.joins(cc: { bb: :aa }).where(aas: { name: 'xxx' })
```

As `cc`, `bb`, `aa` in a reverse order starting from `dd` have a belongs_to relationship between themselves, they're expressed in their single form.

Also note that the `.where(aas: { name: 'xxx' })`, the aas is the plural for `aa`